# Can Rest-Assured's response payload be stored and used across multiple classes?

Tags: java, rest-assured

With Rest-Assured, I send a GET request and get the correct response as requested. I am able to then assert that the correct HTTP status code is returned.

```
public class MyClass{

  private static Response response;
  RestUtil restUtil = new RestUtil();


  public void sendGetRequestT{
    RequestSpecification httpRequest = given()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json");

    response = httpRequest
            .when()
            .get(restUtil.getUrl()).andReturn();
  }


 
  public void verifyStatusCode() {
    int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
  }}
```

Because I would need to verify the correct status code every time with new requests, I thought it was a smart idea to move the `verifyStatusCode()` to a `util` class so that I can call it whenever needed, so I put the implementation that verifies status code in a separate class:

```
public class RestUtil {
  public static Response response;

  public String url = https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users;


  public void verify200() {
    int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    System.out.println("Status code: " + statusCode);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(200);

  }

}
```

Now, in the test class, I called the `verify200()` method but got a NullPointerException:

```
public class MyClass{
    
      private static Response response;
      RestUtil restUtil = new RestUtil();
    
    
      
      public void sendGetRequestT{
        RequestSpecification httpRequest = given()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    
        response = httpRequest
                .when()
                .get(restUtil.getUrl()).andReturn();
      }
    
    
     
      public void verifyStatusCode() {
        restUtil.verify200(); // NullPointerException thrown here
      }}
```

It looks like using the `response` across multiple classes is not possible, or perhaps I am doing something wrong. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having public static variables is not a good idea.  In addition, the Response variable in RestUtil has no relationship to the one in MyClass, so it is null. A better approach is to pass the Response into your util method such as:

```
public class RestUtil {

  public static void verify200(Response response) {
    int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    System.out.println("Status code: " + statusCode);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(200);

  }

}
```

Then in MyClass:

```
public class MyClass{
    
      private Response response;
     
      public void sendGetRequestT() {
        RequestSpecification httpRequest = given()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    
        response = httpRequest
                .when()
                .get(restUtil.getUrl()).andReturn();
      }     
     
      public void verifyStatusCode() {
        RestUtil.verify200( response); 
      }}
```

Comment: Thanks it works OK in `MyClass` when I called the `verify200( response)` method. I decided to check if it will work in multiple classes, so I created an additional class called `MyClassTwo`. The new class has a similar GET request as `MyClass` but has its own unique response. I then called `RestUtil.verify200( response)` in `MyClassTwo`,  but got the dreaded `nullPointerException`. Is there something I need to do in `MyClassTwo` or additional classes in order to be able to call RestUtil.verify200( response)` successfully?

Comment: Can't tell w/o seeing the code, but did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: also a better design would be to create a base class with the function then derive you classes from that and not have to duplicate code